# Center Element of Unknown Height within Other Element and/or Browser Window

Tags: html, css

### I wish to centre (both horizontally and vertically) an element of any width/height within another other element and/or within the browser window.

*I would ideally like a solution that works whether I'm trying to centre content within an element on the page or within the browser window itself.*

---

I realise other questions address various aspects of what I'm attempting to do, but the answers I have read thus far have been unsatisfactory for me.

I am looking for a solution that:

- **uses purely HTML + CSS** (I see there some JS solutions)
- **doesn't use tables** (or divs with "display: table" etc property)
- **is not reliant on fixing the height of the centred element** (I see some solutions work with fixed height + negative top margins)
- **will work** for centring an element **within another a div** or **within the entire browser window**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a long time searching the web and experimenting with this myself. In the end, I stumbled upon the solution documented here:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

...which employs **vertical-align: middle** and a "ghost element" (required for vertical-align to work) created with the psuedo-class **:before** so as to avoid non-semantic markup.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centered">
        This div will be centered.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 650px;
}
```

---

To center the above within the **entire browser window**, the following CSS is required:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- This solution **will not work** for -IE7
- The original solutions employs **width: 1px** and **margin-right: -0.25em** on the ghost element. I have replaced with **width: 0px**